# how Alexa manages my TP-Link HS110 smart wifi plug

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have an Alexa "Echo 7QE", and a smart wifi plug "TP-Link HS110", both connected to the same wifi network at home.

They work perfect.

a) plug controlled from Android, using "Smart Life"

b) Alexa configured perfect, using Android "Amazon Alexa"

c) Alexa discovered the plug and manages it under my voice control. Perfect.

Now I am asking myself what kind of technology they are using.
How do they communicate?

Unfortunately my Google searches are quite meaningless, maybe because I don't ask the proper questions.

I read Alexa uses AWS Lambda.
TP-Link also has a Cloud API

But I don't know how to match it all together.

A simple question: does Alexa talk direct to TP-Link over my local wifi network or
the communication is through some cloud ?

If so (local), what port is it using ?

Thanks for any pointers.